# Ruby on Rails controller (newbie)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, weather-api

Below is very simple Ruby code that gets the weather.  I'm trying Rails for the first time and am having a hard time adding the ruby code to my pages_controller.rb

*My question is how to best add the code into my controller.*

I haven't seen any tutorials that breaks this down simply. Any help/examples are appreciated.

```
def your_destination
    puts "Where are you going?"
    @trip_destination = gets.chomp
    HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/#######key######/geolookup/conditions/q/#{@trip_destination}.json")
end 

def weather_values(your_destination)
    current_temp = your_destination.parsed_response['current_observation']['temp_f'].to_s
    current_condition = your_destination.parsed_response['current_observation']['weather'].to_s
    puts "It is " + current_temp + " and " + current_condition + "!"
end

weather_values(your_destination)
```

Comment: What tutorial are you reading? It's steering you completely in the wrong direction, none of this is even close to Rails, that's just Ruby. Have you tried something like [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/)?

Comment: Sounds fun, HTTP Party :P

Answer (score 0):

This isn't rails. This is plain ruby. Try railstutorial.org. they have an excellent eBook you can read online for free